# How to properly install older mercurial on Mac?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, mercurial

I'm trying to install mercurial 3.6.3. I installed the binary package, but when I run hg on my terminal, it says
`hg: command not found`
I tried exporting the path
`"export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"" >> ~/.bash_profile` but then it says
`/usr/local/bin/hg: No such file or directory`

How do I install the binary package so that it gets installed in `/usr/local/bin`?

fyi, I also tried `pip install mercurial@3.6.3`, which is successfully installed in `/Users/<whoami>/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`, but not in `/usr/local/bin`.